# How to send html dynamic data to external python variable?

Tags: html, flask-sqlalchemy

I know that maybe it's a basic question, but i spent some time without finding a proper answer. I want to pull the text of a p element that changes dynamically, based on user's clicks in page, and assign this text to a python variable in the app.py file,so that it will be sent to database. I use Flask and SQLAlchemy. I tried to pull the data with Beautifullsoup but it sends only the basic text, without the dynamic content. I also tried all variables of request.get, request.args etc but nothing worked properly. Could you help please?

html data ("test" + any additional dynamic data):

```
<form method="post" action = "/choice_send">
<label for="choice"> <b> selection:</b> </label>
<p id="choice" name ="choice"> **test:** </p>
<input type="submit"/>
```

app.py piece of code (i want to assign the data in the bold field):

```
data = Selection("something", **request ???**)
db.session.add(data)
db.session.commit()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're dealing with dynamic content, possibly with javascript in the mix, you probably you be better off using **selenium** in order to employ your dynamic scraping. Requests and BeautifulSoup are suitable to handle static content.